# Gujarati Webpage not showing Perfectly in Webview

Tags: android, fonts, webview, android-webview, android-fonts

I am opening WebPage which contains Gujarati language but its showing just English words in Android `WebView`.

So how can i supports Gujarati words also.

You can see difference in following images:

```
String url = "http://www.police.gujarat.gov.in/dgp/CMS.aspx?Search=PS";
webView =  (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

### Webpage Showing Like This:

[image: Webpage Showing Like This]

### Android WebView Showing like this:

[image: Android WebView Showing like this]

### Edited:

> As i give answer of this question i am succeed but i want to finally
>   display `Gujarati` links in unsupported Devices, How can i? Help me
>   for that please.

Comment: Does the device have a font containing Gujarati characters?

Comment: No, Default any device not providing Gujarati Fonts.

Comment: Did you try opening other websites with Gujarati fonts ?
Can you try opening http://gujaratilexicon.com
or http://aksharnaad.com and check if they are displaying properly or not?

Comment: Thanks to all for valuable response, i got solution, check answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got the solution:

I have run this application **in emulator** thats why it is not displaying Gujarati fonts (may be gujarati lang. is not supported in emulator) but now It is **perfectly running on device**.

> Sometimes it happens with emulator that our application is running correctly on device but not in emulator.

Comment: but my device does not support gujarati language... same time this kind of page showing.

Comment: It's perfectly working in jellybean version mobile.There is no Gujarati font problem.

Comment: This is not a solution at all, there is a large number of devices which doesn't support Gujarati language. Even the epic Androids like Motorola and Nexus don't support Gujarati language.

Comment: If you are seeking for an answer, kindly remove this answer as accepted to display this question as "unanswered".

Comment: @Mann That is the answer dear, There is now way to support if your device not support itself.